# Can't use RecyclerView in my Android library project

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-recyclerview, android-library

I have an Android library project and want to include a class that extends `RecyclerView.Adapter`. My `build.gradle` file includes the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

Despite this, I cannot import RecyclerView in any java file; it even does not show up in the code completions popup in Android Studio (Control+Space). What's wrong?

Comment: Smart suggestions box in Android Studio is Option/Alt + Space

Comment: I meant code completion, but that doesn't matter, it's not present in either case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rebuilt the project
and clean it

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer, if you elaborate on how building and cleaning solves the issue, then you have more of an answer

Comment: Well, that worked (and now I feel dumb). My best guess would be something about the way gradle caches things requires cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same problem. Unfortunately your accepted answer did not worked for me. what i did was----
went to my library gradle file(***build.gradle(Modules:youLibraryname)***) and added the class path for RecyclerView. Something like this,

```
dependencies{ 

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'

}
```

Hope this helps to someone! :)